# Emotions.js or Styled-components What does ThemeProvider provides?

Tags: styled-components, emotion

It seems theme is just a javascript object.

Can we define theme in a javascript file and import them when we need?

So `ThemeProvider` saves you from having to do `manual import` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea behind the `ThemeProvider` is that it will automatically pass the theme object that you create down the render tree as props, so you don't have to manually do that.

To answer your question in more detail lets say you want to provide a dark and light theme in your web app there are two ways you can do that either passing the theme object manually to the components based on the active theme style or you could just pass it once and it will take care of everything.

Here's a small example:

```
const lightTheme = {
  backgroundColor: "#fff",
  color: "#000"
}

const darkTheme = {
  backgroundColor: "#000",
  color: "#fff"
}

const Heading = styled.h1`
  color: ${props => props.theme.color};
` 

export const App = () => {
  const [darkThemeActive, setdarkThemeActive] = useState(false);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={darkThemeActive ? darkTheme : lightTheme}>
      <Heading>Hello world!!</Heading>
      {/* This will override the theme prop thats being passed to the Heading by ThemeProvider */}
      <Heading theme={{color: "green}}>Hello world!!</Heading>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}
```

Comment: To expand on this, Emotion's Theming is just React Context; it doesn't really do anything on top. The benefit of using it over React Context directly is more of a quick of the way Emotion operates, which results in Emotion inserting their own Context provider and consumer between your parents and children (typical higher order component, but around anything you pass a `css` prop to). Since Emotion is already doing this, carrying the theme with it is minimal additional work.